# How to change the behavior of the windows key in Windows 11

Tags: windows, keyboard, remap

It might seem silly, but I can't find a way around that...

On my professional laptop, running Windows 11, I want to change the behavior of the windows key.

Right now, when hitting the windows key, it pops up the start menu, which I find quite annoying. I'd like it to have the behavior of WindowsKey+Tab, i.e. show the content of the actual desk.

And here the little difficulty on top of that, I can't use the Microsoft Store to install software that helps with this, because my company has turned it off for safety reason.

I've tried with :

_ Keyboard and Mouse Center : does not pick up my keyboard

_ Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator : don't work with the windows key

Comment: Just a thought but if your company has disabled the store, they could have disabled the mapping of the keys as well... The only way around it would be the techs that disables the options. Other than that if the IT guys disabled the mapping then your out of luck.

Comment: @CampNerd I can remap other keys

Comment: welcome. that's a question for https://superuser.com/ but it's not programming-related

Answer (score 3):

If its allowed i would go with the PowerToys Tool from Microsoft via GitHub:
[PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases)

After the installation you will find a Keyboard Manager if you are starting PowerToys.

There you can Remap a Key or a Shortcut. And you will find a "WIN" Key where you can map your Windows Key to your needs.

Comment: It worked ! Thks

Comment: This also worked for me, but I had to do it using "Remap a key" instead of "Remap a shortcut" like I originally tried. Thanks!